# ResourceManager.GetString gives localization with wrong encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, localization, resource-files, resgen

I use `ResourceManager` to localize strings in my web forms application. The application supports `en-us` and `sv-se`. The strings are fetched correctly from the respective resource files, but when they are displayed, unicode characters come as junk values.

`resources.sv-se.restext`

```
...
ContactInfoFormatPrimary={0} (primär)
...
```

Output

[image]

Code that gets the resource:

```
ResourceManager resourceManager  = GetResourceManager(...)
...
text = resourceManager.GetString(resourceId);
```

I tried debugging the code, and the text returned is `{0} (prim�r)`

What is causing the resource to decode incorrectly?

UPDATE:

I was able to use the same architecture in a console app and obtain the correct string, is there anything related to application configuration that i need to take care of?

Comment: Displayed *where* (web / desktop) and with what font? This is typically a font or output encoding issue.

Comment: Does not look like a font issue, as the debug window of VS displays the same.

Comment: This went wrong when the string was entered.  Crystal ball says that you are using text files instead of .resx files to localize and they don't have a BOM.

Comment: I use the `restext` files for localization.

Comment: Are you sure you are saving the `restext` files as UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are not saving your resource text files (`.txt`, `.restext`) as `UTF-8` or `UTF-16`/`Unicode`. See the following paragraph from the [MSDN documentation of `Resgen.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_2):

> A text file that contains resources must be saved with UTF-8 or Unicode (UTF-16) encoding unless it contains only characters in the Basic Latin range (to U+007F). Resgen.exe removes extended ANSI characters when it processes a text file that is saved using ANSI encoding.

The easiest way to **check the enconding** of a text file is to open it in `Notepad`, click `Save as...` in the `File` menu and check what's displayed in the `Encoding` drop down in the lower right corner. It should be set to `UTF-8` or `Unicode`.

To **fix the encoding** just select `UTF-8` or `Unicode` in the `Save as...` dialog of `Notepad` and hit `Save` overwriting the original file.

Comment: I used notepad++>> encoding>> convert to utf-8. Thanks for the lead.